# Unable to connect to Node server using Socket.io

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, xcode, socket.io

Im unable to connect to my Node server using Socket.io. I have been following these two tutorials http://www.appcoda.com/socket-io-chat-app/ and http://socket.io/get-started/chat/ but I cant seem to figure out where i'm going wrong. My goal is to connect my Node server to an ios app in Xcode. Here is the **server file**:

```
//require HTTP module/create server
var app = require ('http').createServer();

//Port Number
app.listen(3000) 

//Run Server
var io = require('socket.io')(app);{
  console.log('Listening on *:3000');
};

//Connection
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

When I run the server via terminal, i get `Listening on *:3000` as the output

(According to the tutorial) I then import the **Socket.io Source folder** and create the `SocketIOManager.swift` file as well as edit my `AppDelegate.swift` file

[image]
[image]

According to both tutorials I'm suppose to read `a user connected` when I open the simulator and `user disconnected` when i close it. However i get nothing in terminal. And i'm not sure what this means because i'm not getting any errors in Xcode.

Also when I run the server and open a browser i get the following:

[image]

I'm not sure if the browser issue relates or not but im putting it out there. Im only trying trying to connect my server to the app. I am looking forward to the `a user connected` message because that will verify a connection. If there is another way to test for a connection kindly let me know. Frankly, if there is a more simplified way to connect my server to the app, that would be greatly appreciated. I am open to any additional questions and of course comments.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

[image]

I have `SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()` in my viewcontroller as is but I still cannot establish a connection. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Not sure if this is just a problem when you put it in SO, or if your code has the same problem, but it looks like there is a syntax issue on the line below `// run server`

Comment: Did you call establishConnection() function when your simulator display the View Controller? You can't just call localhost:3000 at your browser as your HTTP server does not have any routing. Consider reading this official socket.io documentation http://socket.io/docs/

Comment: Can you share the syntax error that youre seeing because it is not showing up on my IDE and my server starts without any problems @MattAltepeter

Comment: I have `SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()` in my viewcontroller. Is that what you were referring to? @DylanLaw